# Figure de style: mélange entre un adjectif et un nom homonymes

Tags: synonymes, figure-de-style

Entendu:

> Est-ce que cette veste est imperméable ? Si oui, tu pourrais l'acheter
> pour remplacer le tien.

J'ai trouvé cette phrase très amusante. Je n'y vois rien d'incorrect à proprement parler, juste un tour de passe-passe entre l'adjectif et le nom. Mais ce tour aurait-il un nom ?
NB: nous avions parlé auparavant de mon imperméable qui ne l'était plus. (ceci est un ajout suite aux commentaires)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le plus approchant serait l'**antanaclase elliptique**.

[Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antanaclase):

> Il existe l'antanaclase elliptique (proche du zeugma) qui est une tournure de phrase dans laquelle un mot est utilisé une seule fois (elliptique) mais avec deux sens différents.

Comment: Merci. Oui ça me faisait un peu penser à un zeugme. C'est ma grand-tante qui va être fière ;)

Answer (score -3):

Il y a une erreur dans la seconde partie : « veste » est un nom féminin et donc il faut accorder le pronom possessif et écrire « Si oui, tu pourrais l'acheter pour remplacer **la tienne** ? ».

On ne parle pas de tour lorsqu'il s'agit de questions, c'est à dire de la syntaxe propre aux questions. Tout ce que l'on peut dire est que la forme familière est utilisée pour la seconde question. Au lieu de la construction interrogative formelle « *pourrais-tu* » c'est la forme pour la construction affirmative qui est utilisée.

Une autre particularité est l'utilisation spéciale de « oui » ; dans ce cas aussi il n'est pas habituel de parler de tour. On dit plutôt qu'il s'agit d'un principe de grammaire. Néanmoins, ce principe ne porte pas de nom apparemment. Voilà ce qui en est dit dans LBU à la section 1107.

> Autres emplois de « oui », « si » et « non ».
> « Non » peut être un adverbe (§ 1012) ou un élément de composition (§ 179, b, 2°).
> « Oui », « si » et « non » (parfois concurrencé par pas) peuvent tenir lieu d'une proposition ou d'un syntagme (§ 220, h) : Il dit que « OUI » ou que « SI », que « NON » (Cf. § 416, a). —
> «Si OUI »,  « SINON », « si PAS » (§ 1154, b, 2°). — Je le connais. Toi, NON (ou PAS). — Tu ne le
> connais pas. Moi, SI (ou OUI, etc.). — J'aimerais mieux NON (ou PAS), 1030, c, 1°. —
> Partez-vous ou NON (ou PAS) ? § 1030, b, 1°. — Ne dire ni OUI ni NON, § 1105, c.

Comme  selon les termes dans LBU, « oui » *tient lieu* d'une proposition c'est exactement ce qui est appelé dans les termes de CGEL (Quirk et al) une « pro-form ». Ce terme ou un calque convenable semble cependant n'avoir pas encore été utilisé en français.

Mises à part les particularités grammaticales auxquelles je fais référence il n'y a pas de tour dans ces phrases ni de de nom homonyme (« [le tien](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/le_tien) » est un pronom).

Comment: C'est un peu triste de voir une réponse recherchée avec des votes négatifs, mais la question faisait référence au fait que "le tien" (outre l'erreur grammaticale) pointe implicitement vers "ton imperméable" (et non ta veste). L'auteur pensait que c'était une figure de style (plutôt qu'un oubli d'un "un" avant imperméable ou un accord fautif).

Comment: @JeremyGrand Oui, bien sûr, on peut se laisser aller à du salmigondi, mais on n'est pas tenu de le relever comme significatif ;  je n'avais quand même pas remarqué cet idée et je vous remercie de me la montrer ; c'est un vice de pensée .à connaitre.

Comment: @JeremyGrand Un vote négatif n'est pas une sanction contre le répondant mais sert à donner son opinion sur la qualité de la réponse par rapport à la question posée. Il serait absurde de ne pas signaler les réponses qui répondent à coté des questions sous prétexte que leurs auteurs ont passé du temps à les rédiger mais ça arrive parfois. Un vote négatif est une incitation à corriger si c'est possible ou à supprimer les réponses qui n'apportent rien. Un vote négatif peut très bien être retiré après une correction pertinente, tous les votes négatifs disparaissent si la question est supprimée.

Comment: @JeremyGrand Pourquoi écris-tu *pensait que c'était une figure de style* ? Il ne fait pas de doute qu'il s'agit d'une figure de style, l'OP cherchait juste à savoir si elle avait un nom. Il n'y a pas non plus d'erreur grammaticale puisque *le tien* se réfère à *mon/ton imperméable* qui avait déjà été mentionné explicitement, mais la référence aurait tout aussi bien pu être implicite après la seule utilisation de l'adjectif *imperméable*.

Comment: @jlliagre je faisais plutôt référence au fait qu'on avait quelqu'un qui avait fait des efforts pour écrire une réponse hors-sujet (et donc votée négativement) sans que personne ne lui indique en quoi la réponse était hors-sujet. D'où mon commentaire. Ensuite, sur la référence. Cette réponse et mon commentaires dataient d'avant la précision ajoutée par jcm69. Nous n'avions pas assez de contexte pour être sûrs qu'il ne s'agisse pas d'une faute de frappe. Personnellement, je l'avais compris comme l'OP, mais ça aurait pu être un accident.

Comment: @jlliagre Les figures de style n'ont de réalité que dans la mesure où la phrase reste grammaticale et respecte les rapports sémantiques entre les mots. Il n'y a pas de référent pour « le tien » dans le contexte ; le seul référent à une chose formulée dans le contexte c'est « veste » et donc on conclut soit à l'erreur soit au non sens. On ne devrait voir là-dedans qu'un vice d'expression. Même s'il a été question d'un imperméable dans la phrase précédente la communication est scabreuse : « remplacer »  signifie "renouveler", pas "créer pour mettre à la place de qqc").

Comment: @JeremyGrand J'ai malheureusement renoncé à expliquer à LPH pourquoi je votais négativement certaines de ses réponses, et ce n'est pas rare, car il n'est quasiment jamais arrivé que ce soit productif. Ce ne sont que d'interminables échanges stériles qui ne sont pas ce pour quoi je viens ici. Je ne me souviens que d'une fois où il a changé d'avis et c'était il y a deux ans. Je l'ai même bookmarkée... d'une pierre blanche ;-)  https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/82104/2018/8/22

Comment: @jlliagre Ne racontez pas des sornettes. Un grand nombre de fois j'ai suivi vos corrections et avis et j'ai fait les rectifications que vous indiquiez, bien heureux que quelqu'un rende mes écrits plus intelligents. On retrouvera les cas si l'on y passe du temps, il n'y a pas de doute là-dessus. Seulement, il existe des cas (dans un domaine où compte peut-être plus l'opinion que le fait) où je n'arrive pas à vous suivre ou ne peut pas vous suivre.

Comment: Donc la phrase ***Je te dis que tu es Pierre et sur cette pierre je bâtirai mon Église*** n'est pas une figure de style et n'est pas grammaticale puisqu'elle ne respecte pas les "rapports sémantiques entre les mots". On peut en rester là. Au revoir.

Comment: @jlliagre Intéressant! D'après cette source la pierre n'est pas Pierre, mais ce qu'il vient de dire: « Qu’est-ce que c’est que la pierre sur laquelle le Christ bâtit son église ? Pas sur Satan quand même ! Mais plutôt sur ce que Pierre vient faire de bien juste avant : il vient de dire à Jésus : « Tu es le Christ, le Fils du Dieu vivant. » (Matthieu 16:16). Il est plus probable que ce soit cela, la Pierre sur laquelle bâtir l’Eglise Universelle : la personne de Jésus comme Christ (salut de Dieu pour l’univers), et fils du Dieu vivant. » (1/2)

Comment: @jlliagre https://jecherchedieu.ch/question/quelle-est-la-signification-de-tu-es-pierre-et-que-sur-cette-pierre-je-batirai-mon-eglise/ (2/2)

Comment: @JeremyGrand "un accident"... Oui. Ça aurait pu. Le titre et le texte auraient aussi pu lever l’ambiguïté. Mais pour ça, il aurait fallu accorder un peu de crédit à l'OP ;)